# Write file to response problem

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am having trouble writing a file to the response stream (sandbox solution).

The final line of this code block throws a null reference exception.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
     String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "performance.xlsx"));

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = 
     "application/vnd.openxmlformats officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

memStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

HttpContext.Current.Response.End() (This line);
```

This works fine on a normal ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the limitations of a sandbox solution you cannot achieve what you want to do.

This will have to be done as a Farm solution as the Namespaces you are trying to use are restricted.

(Please someone prove me wrong) :(

There are a few extra for 365, but the ones that effect you cross over.

[**Sandbox/365 Namespace Rules**](http://o365fxcoprules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20Rules&version=1)

Answer (score 0):

The Sandbox lives in it's own process and the `HttpContext.Current` is different from the `HttpContext.Current` in ASP.NET (that lives in IIS and the W3WP.exe process). Learn more about [limitations of Sanbox solutions in Wictor's post](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Understanding-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox-limitations.aspx).

Have you tried alternative approach of using the [the embedded resources](http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/06/30/embedding-resources-in-sandbox-solutions/)?

Comment: @user1786107 An embedded resource perhaps wouldn't work though, I know I am presuming but that spreadsheet would want to be editable, i.e. in a document library?